# Avoid nesting of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, coding-style

is there a way to avoid the "nesting" of functions like

```
f[f[f[a, b], c], d]
```

where a, b, c, d are lists and f is a function that merges two lists with certain rules using a For-Loop

```
For[i = 1, i <= len, i++, 
  L[[i]] = func[x[[i]], x[[i]] ];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

#### EDIT

Included code

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  [L = x; 
   For[i = 1, i <= len, i++,  
     L[[i]] = x[[i]]*y[[i]]] //. Rules; L]
```

Comment: The first expression is simply `Fold[f,{a,b,c,d}]`. There are better ways to define `f` as well but you haven't provided enough information, please provide the full definition i.e. `f... := ...` if you want help with that.

Comment: Step 1: Read the documentation and tutorials  provided with the software. This is easily found there.

Comment: @Pickett, thanks, I was looking for this! Posted the definition of f above. Thanks for your offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* create four random lists for example *)
{a, b, c, d} = RandomInteger[100, {4, 20}];

(* some rules... *)
rules = {1 -> 0, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 5};

(* some function *)
f[a_, b_] := a*b;

(* do it *)
result=Fold[f /. rules, {a, b, c, d}]
```

Notes:

- Don't use uppercase initials for user-defined symbols. You may clash
  with built-ins.
- Operations on lists of same length (implied by yourOP) can almost
  always be vectorized. Using *For* is generally inefficient and poor
  *Mathematica* coding (there are exceptions).
- Read the documentation, tutorials, and tutorial-like questions on
  this site and get a basic understanding of how *Mathematica* works. This is not an interactive documentation source...

Comment: I was looking for the `Fold` command. Thanks for your advice, however I have seen several books which use uppercase initials for user-defined symbols?!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are really asking, but perhaps this will be of interest to you.

```
{x, y} = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}};

p[x_List, y_List] := Inner[Times, x, y, List]
p[x, y]
```

> ```
> {a e, b f, c g, d h}
> ```

or

```
q[x_List, y_List] := Thread[Times[x, y]]
q[x, y]
```

> ```
> {a e, b f, c g, d h}
> ```

If these simple ways of producing a list of products sparks your interest, you should look-up[`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inner.html) and[`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) in the Wolfram Documentation Center.

Comment: +1, but the apparent lack of basic understanding of MMA probably means things like *Thread* and *Inner* will be utterly befuddling.

Comment: @rasher. It is my hope that this will encourage the OP to study the built-in functions that I mention. However, your comment has provoked me to add links to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did indeed already look up these concepts. As explained above, I was primarily looking for `Fold` command.